# JavaScript regex for whole word match base on a set of characters

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

```
  div = $('#m');

  var str = 'The cat will run after to mouse';
  strSearch = ['a'];
    
    $.each(strSearch, function(i, word) {
            reg = new RegExp('\\b(' + word + ')\\b', 'gi');
            newWords = str.replace(reg, function(results) {
                return '<mark>' + results + '</mark>';
            });
    
    div.html(newWords);
```

When I run this code it only highlights the 'a' in 'cat' and 'after' I would like it to highlight the whole word.

Comment: Using `\ba\b` only matches an `a` char as a word, which will not match in the current example string.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\w*a\w*` to match the whole word:

- `\w` matches any word character
- `*` is zero or more

**Demo**

```js
var div = $('#m'),
  str = 'The cat will run after the mouse',
  strSearch = ['a'],
  newWords = null;

$.each(strSearch, function(i, word) {
  var reg = new RegExp('\\w*' + word + '\\w*', 'gi');
  newWords = str.replace(reg, function(results) {
    return '<mark>' + results + '</mark>';
  });
});

div.html(newWords);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><div id="m"></div><style>#m { font-size: 28px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; } mark { display: inline-block; background: yellow; font-weight: bold; }</style>
```